# Android HTML connection failed because of website mobile version

Tags: android, httpconnection

I made a small application that download pictures from a website. But when I'm opening the HttpURLConnection with the right url, it's open the mobile version of this website. How can I open the real one please ? Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `User-Agent` using :

```
//HttpURLConnection connection;
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","YOUR-USER-AGENT");
```